# about class declaration in header file C++

Tags: c++

Here is the problem. I need to write header file with two classes, say class A and class B.

in class A I have function that uses object of class B and vice versa, i.e. in class B I have function that uses objects of class A.

If A declared first then there would be error that class B has not been declared.
How to deal with it? I try declare function of a class A after declaration of class B:

```
void classA::myfunc (classB *b);
```

But  I got the error that function myfunc is not declared.
Experienced people in C++, what to do?

Added:
here is a good link [about header](http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/headerfileincludepatterns.htm)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need a pointer to a class on a header, not the full object, just add a forward declaration, dont include the header of the pointer's class.

I'm sure that you just use pointers to access that classes that one have a reference to another, dont you? You know, because if you use instances, you got a instance looping. Use forward declarations.

Here's a example of how you can use forward declarations:

A.h

```
class B;
class C;
class D;
class E;

class A {
    B* pointer; //To just have a pointer to another object.
    void doThings(C* object); //if you just want to tell that a pointer of a object is a param
    D* getThings(); //if you wanna tell that a pointer of such class is a return.
    E invalid(); //This will cause an error, because you cant use forward declarations for full objects, only pointers. For this, you have to use #include "E.h".
};
```

To illustrate how can have a class that mentions one that pointers its type:

B.h

```
class A;
class B {
    A* pointer; //That can be done! But if you use a includes instead of the forward declarations, you'll have a include looping, since A includes B, and B includes A.
}
```

As mentioned by Tony Delroy (Many thanks to him) You should not ALWAYS use this design. It's provided by the  C++ compiler, but its not a good practice. The best is to provide reference header, so your code would look like:

A.h

```
#include "B.fwd.h"
#include "C.fwd.h"
#include "D.fwd.h"
#include "E.fwd.h"

class A {
    B* pointer; //To just have a pointer to another object.
    void doThings(C* object); //if you just want to tell that a pointer of a object is a param
    D* getThings(); //if you wanna tell that a pointer of such class is a return.
    E invalid(); //This will cause an error, because you cant use forward declarations for full objects, only pointers. For this, you have to use #include "E.h".
};
```

and yours forward headers like this:

B.fwd.h:

```
class B;
```

In your fwds, you should have your class forward declaration, and any typedefs that comes with it.

I'm not mentioning the `#pragma once`, or the `#ifndef B.H...` you know they'll be there :D

Your code would be on a standard defined by  [`<iosfwd>`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-3.4/iosfwd-source.html)  and better to maintain, specially, if they are templates.

Comment: That's not only for pointers, also for methods parameters and return type.

Comment: Yes I know, but i did not said that it was just for pointers, i said that if you dont need the full object, that is, the implementation. And ah, sorry me, but why did you marked my answer and @boydc one as not useful? this is not true, lol

Comment: The declaration, not the implementation :) And also if you need to know the object size, typically when declaring instance variable of that type.

Comment: forward declarations are a great technique!  I use them routinely.  Not sure why someone voted down this answer tbh.

Comment: @Geoffroy Sorry man, but if you want to calculate the size of an object, its surely that you want the full object to do this. You cant calculate the size of a `class A;`, but of course you can calculate the size of a `class A { B* pointer; };` also, its told that forward declarations are for headers, you wont put any implementation in a header. you doesnt want to access members of a pointer in a header, and obvious, you doesnt want to get the size of a object there too.

Comment: @Gtoknu thatnk for your answer. you provided example with two different headers. Is it good to use declaration of several classes in one header?

Comment: @michael glad to help :D Yes it is. If you want to take a look, several big libs use this, like OGRE. I will edit my answer, wait please

Comment: Check my answer again, please.

Comment: why people minus this answer? pretty good explanation in code comments

Comment: -1: your "holy rule" is bad practice.  If a forward declaration of B is needed, best practice is to provide a forward declaration header e.g. B.fwd.h (as per the Standard library's iosfwd).  This is important because 1) the forward declaration should be maintained with the other B files and included from them to provide compile-time consistency checks, 2) code changes such as a move to `template <typename T> class Basic_B { ... }; typedef Basic_B<int> B;` won't break client code.

Comment: Thanks @Tony Delroy, but i did not mean to bother the guy. I just told that forward declaration was the way to go. Why does guys around here think that if we have not included a part of an answer, the answer would be totally wrong?

Comment: @Gtoknu it would be nice if you just edit your answer, to get rid of "holly rule" and explain what Tony Delroy said.

Comment: @Gtoknu: "if we have not included a part of an answer, the answer would be totally wrong?" - I'm not sure. I didn't downvote Geoffroy's answer event though it lacked crucial details about where to put the forward declaration, but I did downvote you because I your more detailed answer actively encourages bad (but very common) practice with the example you have. If you feel that unjustified - please explain why my concerns are misplaced I'll upvote (if stackoverflow lets me - it can be restrictive about changing votes).

Comment: @TonyDelroy I have fixed the answers, thanks, you are right. But please, keep in mind that upvotes and downvotes are to tell if the answer is useful, helps to solve the question, or not useful, doesnt helps to solve the question. And not if it is the best way or not.

Comment: Gtoknu: -1 => +1 from me.  I must disagree with your understanding of what votes are for though - answers should ideally answer the question as asked AND provide more general context, techniques and recommendations as probably useful (sometimes they won't be useful to the person who answered the question, but may help others who stumble across it).  An immediate fix that leaves the code fragile and error-prone isn't to be encouraged when better alternatives exist.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer:

```
class classA;
```

Then you defined your classB and then the declaration of classA.

This is called forward-declaration, and is there to solve your problem :)

Comment: Typically you want to declare the common classes, as needed, in a common header. Precompiled headers or a common library header (with enums and classes and such) work well for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a forward declaration of a class before you use it with a ref or ptr.

classA.h:

```
class classB;

class classA {
    void fun(classB * b);
}
```

classB.h:

```
class classA;

class classB {
    void fun(classA * a);
}
```

classA.cpp:

```
#include "classA.h"
#include "classB.h"

...
```

classB.cpp:

```
#include "classA.h"
#include "classB.h"

...
```

Comment: Great answer, i think that one completes the mine. You should do forward declarations in headers, and header includes in .cpps (: